# How do you get console output from Python pool?

Tags: python, console-application, pool

I have some simple code testing latency for browsers which opens multiple instances of Selenium:

```
with Pool(processes=args.number_of_browsers) as pool:
    for i in range(args.number_of_browsers):
        logging.info("Starting job on browser #" + str(i))
        pool.apply_async(run, args=(args.refresh_rate, args.jitter, args.duration, args.url, str(i)))
```

For the purposes of the question, the run function could be as simple as:

```
def run():
    logging.debug("ANYTHING")
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to get console output from the pool library.

Comment: wouldn't you need something like logger = logging.getLogger('pool') and a logger config ?

Comment: @user3732793 ‍♂️ I genuinely don't know

Answer (score 0):

here a basic working logging example in python

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s:%(message)s',
datefmt='%Y%m%d%H%M%S%p', level=logging.DEBUG)

NODE_NAME = 'Test'
logger = logging.getLogger(NODE_NAME)

logger.info('hello')
```

correct logging needs more config